# error: use of undeclared identifier

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to run this code, but I keep getting:

```
:21:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 'r'
for(int s = h - r; s > 0;s--)
```

but I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting the error. Can anyone help me out here?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int h;
    do
    {
        printf("please give me a positive int between 1 and 23: ");
        h = GetInt();
    }
    while (h < 1 || h > 23);
    //get int and store it 


    for(int r = 0; r < h; r++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }

    for(int s = h - r; s > 0;s--)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }      
}
```

Comment: the scope of r is limited to the  loop it is declared

Comment: Undeclared means that you haven't declared the variable in the scope which you are using it in. Try to declare your variables before using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better declare `r` right after `main` begins as in your current code you're declaring `r` only for the `for` loop.

```
int main() {
    int r=0, h=0;

    // add other code here
    // don't forget h=GetInt()

    for(r = 0; r < h; r++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }

    for(int s = h - r; s > 0;s--)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }      
}
```

Comment: thanks! this fixed the error. but now i am getting the following: c:6:10: note: initialize the variable 'r' to silence this warning
    int r, h;    i fixed this by making it: int r = 0, h;   is this correct? or will this mess up the other code if i do it like this?